# speedy update of list of associations

Tags: performance-tuning, associations

Suppose `as` is a list of associations that I want to update.
For example:

```
as = Table[<|"f1"->i,"f2"->2,"f3"->3|>,{i,3}];  (*original*)
as = Append[#,{"f1"->0,"f2"->#f1+10}]& /@ as    (*update*)
```

*Question:* Is this a speedy approach to updating?
If not, what are better approaches?

E.g., can it be preferable to change `as` in place,
and if so how? (I care more about speed than memory.
At the moment, I don't want to convert to a `Dataset`.)

Comment: How large is your Association, and how many of its values are you updating?  And have you seen [`AssociateTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociateTo.html)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I know about `AssociateTo` but (since it has `HoldFirst`) did not see a useful way to exploit it.  The lists of associations are short, but I have to do this many times.  Aside from that, I am interested in the answer more generally.  The only in-place alternatives I have tried use explicit loops and assignment.  For example, `Do[as[[i, "f2"]] = as[[i, "f1"]] + 10; 
 as[[i, "f1"]] = 0;, {i, Length[as]}]`.  Of course, this is much slower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
as = Table[<|"f1"->i,"f2"->2,"f3"->3|>,{i,3}];
as[[All, "f2"]] = as[[All, "f1"]] + 10;
as[[All, "f1"]] = 0;

as
```

> {<|"f1" -> 0, "f2" -> 11, "f3" -> 3|>, <|"f1" -> 0, "f2" -> 12, 
>     "f3" -> 3|>, <|"f1" -> 0, "f2" -> 13, "f3" -> 3|>}

Speed comparison:

```
as = Table[<|"f1"->i,"f2"->2,"f3"->3|>, {i, 10^6}];
as = Append[#,{"f1"->0,"f2"->#f1+10}]& /@ as; //AbsoluteTiming

bs = Table[<|"f1"->i,"f2"->2,"f3"->3|>, {i, 10^6}];
bs[[All, "f2"]] = bs[[All, "f1"]] + 10; //AbsoluteTiming
bs[[All, "f1"]] = 0; //AbsoluteTiming

Normal[KeySort /@ as] == Normal[KeySort /@ bs]
```

> {3.00381, Null}
>
> {0.806365, Null}
>
> {0.612295, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 3):

**OP reports that `AssociateTo[as[[i]], . . .]` no longer works in version 11.3.0**

---

I don't follow the reticence to use [`AssociateTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociateTo.html) you expressed in a comment above.  It seems expressly suited to this purpose, e.g.:

```
big = AssociationMap[#^2 &, Range@1*^6];
new = # -> #^3 & /@ Array[Prime, 1000];
AssociateTo[big, new]; // AbsoluteTiming

big[[71]]
71^3
```

> ```
> {0.00223797, Null}
>
> 357911
>
> 357911
> ```

Can you show me a problem with this?

---

Carl Woll objects that I did not address the list-of-associations in your example. Indeed, but as `AssociateTo` works on [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) one can iterate like this:

```
as = Table[<|"f1" -> i, "f2" -> 2, "f3" -> 3|>, {i, 3}];(*original*)

Do[
 AssociateTo[as[[i]], {"f1" -> 0, "f2" -> as[[i, "f1"]] + 10}],
 {i, Length@as}
]

as
```

> ```
> {<|"f1" -> 0, "f2" -> 11, "f3" -> 3|>,
>  <|"f1" -> 0, "f2" -> 12, "f3" -> 3|>,
>  <|"f1" -> 0, "f2" -> 13, "f3" -> 3|>}
> ```

Comment: The OP has a list of associations, while I think you have a single association.

Comment: In 11.3.0, you cannot use `AssociateTo` with `Part` like this.  (This was the thrust of my comment above.)  What version are you using?  (And what is the timing?)

Comment: @Alan Odd, and a little disappointing! I am using version 10.1.

Comment: @Alan I have made a note of this incompatibility at the top of my answer.  Since I do not have access to the latest versions I think I should let someone that does attempt to answer this now.

Comment: @Alan One thing to check, though I expect it *doesn't* work, is `AppendTo` in direct replacement for `AssociateTo` in my `Do` loop.

Comment: Your `Do` loop works just fine with a simple tweak: `Do[  With[{i = i}, AssociateTo[ as[[i]], ...] ], {i, Length@as}]`

Comment: @JasonB. Yes that works, but it is even slower than the `Do` loop in my comment above.